# Migration of a detailed answer on MathOverflow Meta to Math.SE

Tags: discussion, migration, math-stackexchange

Upon reading Professor Hamkins' detailed answer to this recent   [Question about $i$ versus $-i$](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4968/question-about-i-versus-i) here on MathOverflow Meta, and his accommodating  comments:

> Oh, I see now that this was a meta question, but I answered as though it was on main. Please forgive me.

> I am not sure whether this question/answer is appropriate here on Meta---perhaps it should simply be migrated to the main site? – Joel David Hamkins

May I ask  if he would consider having his answer migrated to the main site of Math.SE as [part of this question/answer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177594/how-to-tell-i-from-i)

Comment: I posted my answer [over on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4106265/413) as you suggested.

Answer (score 6):

You can't migrate *an answer* without migrating the entire thread, which is entirely inappropriate at this point.

You can encourage Joel to take his question to Math.SE, and if there is no suitable question on which he can post it, then he is more than welcome to formulate his own question and post that answer below it.

In either case, moving only an answer is not within the powers of the moderators, and moving the question is not the right path here.

Regardless to that, asking here if *Joel might consider* doing something is also inappropriate. This is Meta MathOverflow, not Meta JoelD.HamkinsOverflow (despite his ultraprolific activity on the site! :-))

Comment: a comment on the answer on MO would indeed be far more appropriate.

Comment: +1 for "this is meta mathoverflow, not meta joelD.hamkinsOverflow"